# How to fix crashes on "Checking info" screen when trying to add a Google account?

Tags: google-account, crashes, google-play-services

I had to remove my Google account to sign out of Gmail, but when I try to log back in I see this screen and then it crashes:

[image: IMG:]

Without this, my Keep, Gmail and even Play Store isn't working and I'm unable to sign into YouTube.

I've tried restarting my phone, clearing app data for all Google apps. I thought this was a Google Play Services problem, so I tried to update it by installing via the latest APK but it always says that "the package is corrupt"

This started when my Gmail app started crashing out of the blue. I tried restarting my phone which didn't help, so I thought I'd sign out and sign back in.

I'm using Android 7 on Redmi Note 4

Answer (score 1):

Although several months too late for OP, the problem described is exactly the same as one I just had to solve on my Mum’s tablet yesterday.

Note that there seems to be at least a couple of different problems that people are reporting that relate to the “Checking Info” screen. The problem I’m referring to is where the Checking Info screen just crashes and disappears, NOT the problem where it freezes.

The symptoms being seen were:

1. Almost none of the Google apps were able to run. The only exception to this was Chrome, which was working fine.
2. When trying to access Google Play Store, I was asked to sign in, but then the Checking Info screen was displayed briefly before it crashed and returned me to the sign in screen.
3. A number of other apps (a seemingly random selection) were crashing as soon I tried to open them.

What I did to fix it:

1. In Settings > Apps I selected the Chrome app and chose the “Uninstall all updates” from the 3-dot menu.
2. I was then able to successfully open the Google Play Store, login, and get past the Checking Info screen.
3. Finally, in the Google Play Store, I found the Chrome app and selected “Update”.

All the affected apps then worked correctly.

Why does this work?
The Checking Info screen has an embedded web browser window in it (called WebView). If Chrome is installed then it provides this capability. I think that during a Chrome update something happened to cause WebView to break. Taking Chrome back to its factory default version removed that fault. Not sure why updating Chrome back to its most recent version then doesn’t cause it to break again - perhaps some error in one of the earlier updates.

Comment: This answer was invaluable in helping me come up with the solution that did actually work for my father's issues with the Checking Info screen: rather than doing "Uninstall updates" for "Google Chrome", in Settings > Apps, select *Android System WebView* and in the 3-dot menu, select "Uninstall updates". From there you should be able to add a Google account in Settings > Accounts > + Add an account > Google.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's too late to answer now but i hope someone else would find it helpful

Sometimes even if you switch account in play store it doesn't allow you to download anything.. it just keeps on showing Waiting for Download.

Go to Settings-->Accounts>Google-->(your email id you removed earlier)-->"Remove account" from top right corner. And then add it from start.