# Can't add work account, "Checking info" crashes imediatly

Tags: google-account

My problem is pretty much the same as this one, except that the solutions didn't work for me.

[How to fix crashes on "Checking info" screen when trying to add a Google account?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204789/how-to-fix-crashes-on-checking-info-screen-when-trying-to-add-a-google-account)

I'm trying to add a new work account, and after entering credentials and the authentication app ping, the "Checking info" page appears and immediately closes. The account is added, but it is not set up properly.

If I go to manage the account, it displays a message saying that something went wrong during sign-in and asks me to try again. When I click on it, the same thing happens (it opens "Checking info" and crashes immediately).

I have tried clearing the cache of everything and uninstalling updates, but nothing works.

ps: During initial setup google was supposed to ask if I wanted to set up a Workspace account, this does not show up.

Specs:

Galaxy s20 FE 5g
Android 12
Original Room not rooted
Google play version 23.33.16

Comment: You forgot to add more details about the used device: manufacturer? phone model name? installed Android version? is the installed ROM genuine, (rooted?) or a custom ROM? what is the version of the installed Google Play Services?